# Google Cloud Speech API Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api, speech

I'm working for a university stage and I have to integrate google cloud speech api in a my html5 page to perform speech recognition. I have two problems:

1) I'm searching around the web and I don't find a suitable library to generate an audio file (flac or wav) from microphone.

2) I don't understand if it is impossible using javascript to perform a Google Speech API recognition or not. If it is not: how can I do, considering I have to manage the event of pushing a button?

Thank you!